Measurability of $\|f(\cdot, x_{2})\|_{L^\infty(X_{1})}$ (proof of Minkowski's inequality)
I am trying to prove Minkowski's inequality for integrals in the case $p = \infty$.

Suppose $(X_{1}, \mu_{1})$ and $(X_{2}, \mu_{2})$ are two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and $f(x_{1}, x_{2})$ is a non-negative measurable function on $X_{1}\times X_{2}$ then $$\Big\|\int f(x_{1}, x_{2})\:\text{d}\mu_{2}\Big\|_{L^{\infty}(X_{1})}\leq \int \|f(x_{1}, x_{2})\|_{L^\infty(X_{1})}\:\text{d}\mu_{2}.$$

I am having trouble at the very first step in showing that $x_{2}\mapsto \|f(\cdot, x_{2})\|_{L^{\infty}(X_{1})}$ is measurable.
Some thoughts:
My idea is to write $\|f(\cdot, x_{2})\|_{L^{\infty}(X_{1})}$ as the limit of a sequence of measurable functions.
(i) The answer posted here suggests that it might be useful to use the fact that $\|g\|_{\infty} = \lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}\|g\|_{p}$ under certain conditions. However, the answer here suggests that in the case when $\|g\|_{\infty} < \infty$ then we need in addition that $\|g\|_{p_{0}} < \infty$ for some $p_{0}\in(0, \infty)$ (which may not be the case). Could we somehow make use of the $\sigma$-finiteness of the spaces?
(ii) The answer here suggests that if $h$ is a non-negative measurable function then $$\|h\|_{\infty} = \sup\Big\{\int hg\:\text{d}\mu : g\geq 0, \|g\|_{1} = 1\Big\}.$$ In this case, for $\mu_{2}$-a.e. $x_{2}$ we may write $$\|f(\cdot, x_{2})\|_{L^{\infty}(X_{1})} = \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\int f(x_{1}, x_{2})g_{m}(x_{1}, x_{2})\:\text{d}\mu_{1}$$ for some sequence of non-negative functions $\{g_{m}\}$ such that for each $m$ and $\mu_{2}$-a.e. $x_{2}$ we have $\|g(\cdot, x_{2})\|_{L^{1}(X_{1})}\leq 1$. However, I am not able to make this argument work since it is not clear that the functions $g_{m}$ are measurable with respect to the product measure on $X_{1}\times X_{2}$.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

It should say $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ in (ii), so they are measurable.

You can use a "double limit" argument: instead of g, consider $g 1_{E_n}$ with $E_n$ of finite measure. Then apply your idea (i). Afterwards let $n \to \infty$.

@PhoemueX thanks a lot for the hint, I was able to figure it out.

Thanks to @PhoemueX for the hint. We may use the $\sigma$-finiteness of $X_{1}$ to write $X_{1} = \bigcup_{n\geq 1}E_{n}$ with $\mu_{1}(E_{n}) < \infty$ and $E_{n}\subseteq E_{n+1}$ for all $n$. Then by the theorem in the answer posted here we can show
Fact 1: For $\mu_{2}$-a.e. $x_{2}$ we have $$\|f(\cdot, x_{2})\chi_{E_{n}}\|_{L^{\infty}(X_{1})} = \lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}\|f(\cdot, x_{2})\chi_{E_{n}}\|_{L^p(X_{1})}.$$
It is also easy to show that
Fact 2: For $\mu_{2}$-a.e. $x_{2}$ we have $$\|f(\cdot, x_{2})\|_{L^{\infty}(X_{1})} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f(\cdot, x_{2})\chi_{E_{n}}\|_{L^{\infty}(X_{1})}.$$
Thus, $x_{2}\mapsto\|f(\cdot, x_{2})\|_{L^{\infty}(X_{1})}$ is the limit of a sequence of measurable functions, hence measurable.
